# Returning the associatedtype of an opaque return type

Tags: swift, generics, associated-types, opaque-result-type

I have a simple protocol with an associated type, and a protocol extension that returns an array of this type.

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Unit
}

extension Foo {
    var allTheFoos: [Unit] {
        return []
    }
}
```

I then have a struct which returns `some Foo` in a computed property, and another computed property that returns the `allTheFoos` array.

```
struct FakeFoo: Foo {
    typealias Unit = Int
}

struct FooFactory {
    var myFoo: some Foo {
        return FakeFoo()
    }

    /* WHICH RETURN TYPE WILL
       PLEASE THE SWIFT GODS?!
     */
    var allTheFoos: [Foo.Unit] {
        return myFoo.allTheFoos
    }
}
```

The return type of `allTheFoos` matches Xcode's autocomplete type suggestion for the `myFoo.allTheFoos` call, but understandably, this yields a:

```
// var allTheFoos: [Foo.Unit] {}
ERROR: Associated type 'Unit' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base
```

My question is: **What return type will make Xcode happy?**

Below are my attempts, and their corresponding errors

```
// var allTheFoos: [some Foo.Unit] {}
ERROR: 'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions
```

```
// func allTheFoos() -> some [Foo.Unit]
ERROR: Associated type 'Unit' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base
```

```
// func allTheFoos<U: Foo.Unit>() -> [U]
ERROR: Associated type 'Unit' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base
ERROR: Cannot convert return expression of type '[(some Foo).Unit]' to return type '[U]'
```

```
// func allTheFoos<U>() -> [U] where U: (some Foo).Unit
ERROR: 'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions
```

FYI: The reason I'm doing this in a computed property in the first place is to keep things clean in some SwiftUI code.

Thanks for any help you can give!

=========== UPDATE ===========

I missed some important stuff in my sample code, so to give some context: the code is used in a unit conversion app, so something that can turn Celsius into Kelvin, Kg into lbs, and anything else into anything else.

```
protocol Unit: Equatable {
    var suffix: String { get }
}

struct Value<UnitType: Unit> {
    let amount: Double
    let unit: UnitType

    var description: String {
        let formatted = String(format: "%.2f", amount)
        return "\(formatted)\(unit.suffix)"
    }
}
```

Value is constrained to a unit type, so that it's not possible to convert Celsius into Litres.

Therefore, we have a `Conversion` protocol that stores all similar units together:

```
protocol Conversion {
    associatedtype UnitType: Unit

    var allUnits: [UnitType] { get }
    func convert(value: Value<UnitType>, to unit: UnitType) -> Value<UnitType>
}

extension Conversion {
    func allConversions(for value: Value<UnitType>) -> [Value<UnitType>] {
        let units = self.allUnits.filter { $0 != value.unit }
        return units.map { convert(value: value, to: $0) }
    }
}
```

So an example of a conversion for Temperature would be:

```
struct Temperature: Conversion {
    enum Units: String, Unit, CaseIterable {
        case celsius, farenheit, kelvin

        var suffix: String {
            switch self {
            case .celsius:   return "˚C"
            case .farenheit: return "˚F"
            case .kelvin:    return "K"
            }
        }
    }

    var allUnits: [Units] { return Units.allCases }

    func convert(value: Value<Units>, to unit: Units) -> Value<Units> {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Finally, the actual app code where the problem occurs is here:

```
struct MyApp {
    var current: some Conversion {
        return Temperature()
    }

    // ERROR: Associated type 'UnitType' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base
    var allConversions: [Value<Conversion.UnitType>] {
        // This value is grabbed from the UI
        let amount = 100.0
        let unit = current.allUnits.first!
        let value = Value(amount: amount, unit: unit)

        return current.allConversions(for: value)
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible. While there are some features in the works that might make parts of this possible in future years (specifically a generalized existential that may work together with opaque return types), it's not quite clear what you really want to happen here and whether that would ever be possible. What does the calling code look like? We can start from there and design something that likely does not require an associated type (which I don't think you really mean here).

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier - I realise now I tried to simplify the problem to post it here, and subsequently removed a good chunk of the important code regarding my intention. Will update now.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at how you've implemented `AnyValue`, I think what you want here is just:

```
var allConversions: [String] {
    let units = self.allUnits.filter { $0 != value.unit }
    return units.map { convert(value: value, to: $0) }.description
}
```

Or something like that. All the algorithms that match what you're describing are just "conversion -> string." If that's the case, all you really want is CustomStringConvertible.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this issue using some Type Erasure:

```
struct AnyValue {
    let description: String

    init<U: Unit>(_ value: Value<U>) {
        self.description = value.description
    }
}
```

allowing for:

```
var allConversions: [AnyValue] {
    // This value is grabbed from the UI
    let amount = 100.0
    let unit = current.allUnits.first!
    let value = Value(amount: amount, unit: unit)

    return current.allConversions(for: value).map(AnyValue.init)
}
```

However, this feels like a clunky solution (and one that opaque return types was introduced to avoid). Is there a better way?

Comment: The problem isn't the clunkiness; the problem is what this would be used for. What would can `allConversions` and do anything with the result? What is the purpose of `allConversions`? (I would start by studying the existing system of `Measurement` in Foundation, and see what problems you're solving. It's not perfect Swift, and there definitely are ways to improve it, but it's a proper starting point for this problem.) If your goal is just to create strings, there are much simpler solutions here.

Comment: For a given value (say 100˚C), I want to instantly get all other possible values for that Dimension (so ˚F, and K). For this use case, your `String` example works great, but I'm still keen to see if conceptually this is possible given the constraint of `some Conversion`. You're right, there is plenty of overlap with `Measurement`, and the only reason I didn't use it is because I'm exploring opaque result types here. I could use it, but since all corresponding `Dimensions` are just static properties, I assume there'd need to be some convenience enums to make things iterate-able.

Comment: This isn't what opaque result types are for, however. The point of an opaque result type is to hide a specific *concrete* type that is known to the compiler, but not to the caller. I think you're trying to treat `some` as if it were an existential (a type eraser). That's now how it works. That's why you can't have `[some P]`. All the elements would have to be some *specific* type (not `P`). The type of `myFoo` in your example is not "any P." It is "the precise type that is returned by `myFoo`, known at compile time, but the caller may only treat it as `P`."